# How can i update a specific data in my sqlite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite

1. This is my Database class.

   ```
   public boolean updatePrediction(String item_ean,String prediction)
   { 
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(ITEM_EAN, item_ean);
   contentValues.put(PREDICTION_TYPE,prediction);
   db.update(TABLE_REPORT,contentValues,PREDICTION_TYPE+"="+,null);
   return true;
   ```
2. This is the activity class code snippet.

   ```
   toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked()) {   
   booleanisUpdated=dbcontroller.updatePrediction(editText.getText().toString(),"4");
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toggle is  on"+isUpdated, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   } else {
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toggle is off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
   }
   });
   ```

When i switch the toggle button the specific data in my case item_ean's prediction_type should change.

Comment: Is SQLiteDatabase is the name of your class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper?

Answer (score 0):

execSQL is for execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

For UPDATE statements, use any of the following instead.

1. update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])
2. updateWithOnConflict(String, ContentValues, String, String[], int)

You must use update for your case like this :

```
public boolean updatePrediction(String item_ean,String prediction){ 
   SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
   contentValues.put(ITEM_EAN, item_ean);
   String[] args = new String[]{prediction};
   db.update(TABLE_REPORT,contentValues,PREDICTION_TYPE+"=?",args);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Nope! It's not updating.

Comment: @Moses can you try the implementation that I put in my answer ?

Comment: @Moses update method return int (the number of rows affected) can you log it ?

Comment: @Moss can you try the last implementation that i punt in my answer?

Comment: String[] args = new String[]{prediction};
   db.update(TABLE_REPORT,contentValues,PREDICTION_TYPE+"=?",args);
   return count;
the log is still the same 
answer is : the updated query is0

Comment: @Moses You are sure to Have data in your TABLE_REPORT withe PREDICTION_TYPE = 4 ?  can you try this :  db.update(TABLE_REPORT,contentValues,PREDICTION_TYPE+"!=?",args);

Comment: Hey @Casablancais the number in the prediction_type column is changing. but the entire column is changed. i don't want that to happen. All i need is to change the value of specific item_ean's prediction_type.